# не работает requests через proxies

Tags: python, requests, get, прокси

Делаю подмену айпишника при получении запроса но выдает ошибку:

> Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000036F14C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера')))

Вот код:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: ваш пример у меня работает ))